# Функции задержки при выводе в браузер

Tags: php, потоки-данных, sleep

Я новичок в программировании и мне непонятно вот что:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

  echo $i;
  sleep(2);

}
```

По моей задумке, на экране сначала бы появился 0, потом через две секунды 1 и через каждых две секунды новая цифра и так до 10. Но они не стали появляться, прошло секунд 20 и только после этого все цифры появились одновременно. Я бы хотел, чтобы вы объяснили, почему такое поведение у функции sleep() и функций задержки вообще (в jquery delay(), вроде). Я слышал, это как-то связано с потоками, буферами и прочим, но, будьте добры, понятным новичку языком объяснить, что такое эти буферы, что такое эти потоки и как они связаны в программировании с функциями задержки. Большое спасибо.

Comment: нужно сбрасывать буфер на каждой итерации чтоб правильно выводилось `for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

  echo $i; flush();
  sleep(2);

}`  а вот почему зависает при таком исполнении.....

Comment: Если выполнить этот скрипт в консоли, то так и будет выводить по очереди. Отсюда можно сделать вывод, что к циклам этот вопрос не имеет отношения.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский зависает из-за того что установлен "буфер из коробки", который не требует написания `ob_start`. Допустим у меня значение буфера из коробки составляет `4096`. Если вы поставите значение `off` то тогда `flush` будет срабатывать как в консоли! Между прочим отвечу сразу на параллельный вопрос по поводу консоли. Да у вас стоит буфер, но в консоли он автоматически теряет свою силу на значение `off`

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, тут не хватает сброса потока вывода при помощи `flush` и/или `ob_flush`.

<s>Во-вторых, браузер, вероятно, тоже умный и рисовать по 2 символа ему лень, поэтому он ждёт заполнения какого-то внутреннего буфера. Попробуй после каждого вывода подключать скрипт, который будет выполнять задержку.</s>
Я был неправ. Браузер корректно обрабатывает куски html:

```
require('http').createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' });
  response.write('<!doctype html><title>Number in 2 seconds</title>');

  ~(function go(i) {
    response.write('<p>' + i);
    response.flush();

    if (i < 11) {
      setTimeout(go, 2000, i + 1);
    } else {
      response.end();
    }
  })(0);
}).listen(8082);
```

Comment: for( $i = 0 ; $i < 100 ; $i++ )
{
    echo $i . '<br />';
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
} вот этот код у меня зараотал. можете объяснить смысл функций flush и ob_flush?

Comment: @Alexander, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191385/php-buffer-ob-flush-vs-flush

Comment: @Alexander, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/554381/178988