# разница между flush() и ob_flush()

Tags: php, потоки-данных, стек

Прошу вас, объясните наконец, ЧТО именно делают эти функции (объясните просто, я новичок) и какая между ними разница.
Не понимаю, хоть убей, на форумах всех используют терминологию, котораял ишь путает тех, кто столкнулся с ними впервые. И что ещё за верхнии и нижнее слои стека буферов? Что за стек буферов? Что за слои? Если кто-то это доступно объяснит - это мне очень поможет. Заранее огромное спасибо

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191385/php-buffer-ob-flush-vs-flush

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если в простых терминах пояснять, то когда вызывается echo/print, то данные идут на вывод (например браузер). Чтобы при многочисленных echo не гонять по байту существует выходной буфер, куда накапливаются выходные данные до какого то объема и при переполнении данные отправляются на выход. Потом снова происходит накопление данных. flush принудительно выбрасывает содержимое буфера в поток вывода.

Например, есть у вас долгая задача, где нужно постоянно досылать в браузер результаты и вы используете echo "информация". Но они накапливаются в буфере и браузер ничего не получит пока буфер не переполнится. flush после echo принудительно отправляет данные. 
Также буфер можно отключить, а в режиме cli его вообще нет.

ob_* позволяет же инициализировать свои вложенные буферы, наслаивая их друг на друга. И при очищении данные такого буфера будут попадать в нижележащий вплоть до дефолтного.
А можно вообще не делать flush, а просто забрать накопленный результат из буфера и уничтожить его.

ob_start открывает новый буфер и все последующие print/echo будут попадать в него. В любой момент вы можете открыть новый буфер, а можете закрыть и сбросить данный на буфер открытый ранее.
То есть это выглядит как слоенный пирог (стек) буферов, где данные пишутся в верхний буфер и только когда все буферы будут сброшены на нижележащие вплоть до дефолтного, только тогда данные уйдут не вывод.

Удобно это использовать в самописном шаблонизаторе. Для сегмента шаблона создаем буфер и потом забираем готовый хтмл и буфер уничтожаем. Или когда вызываем сторонний код который изобилует echo и создает мусор - мы его вызов оборачиваем в ob_* и весь этот мусор оседает там.

то есть flush сбрасывает **системный** буфер на вывод, а ob_flush сбрасывает **последний открытый** буфер через ob_start в **нижележащий** буфер (ob_* или системный)

Comment: Почему [тут](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554355/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80/554363#comment715028_554363) понадобились оба, да ещё и в таком порядке?

Comment: Пре-вос-ход-но. Большое спасибо.

Comment: @Qwertiy не знаю, ob_ лишний если он нигде не стартовал. А так следует помнить, что кроме буфера вывода в пхп данные будут оседать в буфере сервера. Из-за этого приходится по особому конфигурировать сервер, но flush достаточно.(а еще моно сделать @ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);)

Comment: В [другом комментарии](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554355/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80/554363#comment715021_554355) говорится, что просто flush недостаточно.

Comment: flush не достаточно просто. Сам проверял вчера. Сначала flush, потом ob_flush, тогда эффект есть

Comment: @Qwertiy у меня пример с flush+ob_flush не работает вовсе. все упирается в окружение где и как работает php. Но тут  я уже не силен. В случае проблем просто писал заявку админам и оно начинало работать. "хак" flush()+ob_flush() использовать не приходилось. Впрочем и flush последний раз использовал еще на на версии 5.2 вроде.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ прост потому как `ob_flush` очищает и выводит буфер созданыый `ob_start` - 'output buffer start' а `flush` очищает буфер вывода скрипта который и отправляет его вывод в браузер обычно это происходит по окончанию выполнения скрипта.