# Есть ли у PHP аналог SetTimeout, как у javaScript?

Tags: php, timeout

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. Задача: Выполнить php сценарий, но если все условия для его выполнения не готовы, то выполнить его ещё раз, через 10 секунд? Есть ли подобный функционал в PHP?

Comment: Исторически так сложилось, что пхп не использовали для скриптов постоянной работы, только по принципу "выполнение+завершение". С появлением 7-пхп в этом плане стало намного лучше. Когда мне необходимо было организовать подобный функционал, я делал свою реализацию: запускал демона и управлял командами из базы.

Comment: @Stanislav да не изменилось ничего с семеркой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример, цикл ограниченный тремя итерациями (`$i < 3`), которые выполняется с задержкой 10 секунд `sleep(10)`, при необходимости количество итераций можно увеличить и/или добавить какое-то условие вместо `echo`

```
<?php

for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
    $date = new DateTime();
    echo "Итерация № $i, выполнена в " . $date->format("H:m:s") . "<br>";
    sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: Весьма не дурно, почти то что мне нужно. Но вот проблема только в том, что когда я использую это на странице, то например с этим кодом, сама страница грузится 30 секунд ...

Comment: Это связано с буфером вывода на экран, информация не выводиться сразу при каждом echo, а сохраняется в буфер и потом выводиться сразу все (три итерации по 10 секунд длятся как раз 30 секунд), на уровне php это решается очисткой буфера через flush() и ob_flush(), но надо помнить что на уровне веб-сервера так же есть свой буфер, поэтому решать эту задачу надо на конкретной конфигурации и это отдельная тема. Например если будите вместо echo писать сообщение в файла, 30ти секундной задержки не будет и они будут появллятся каждые 10 секунд.

Comment: Вот тут более детально про буфер php можно почитать http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554381/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-flush-%D0%B8-ob-flush

Answer (score 0):

Для подобных целей можно использовать cron.